# Algorithm to yield all

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I was wondering what's wrong with what I have here

```
private static string ReplaceAt(string s, int i, char c)
{
    if(s.Length < 1) // corner case
        return string.Empty;
    var sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    sb[i] = c;
    return sb.ToString();       
}


// returns all strings formed from replacing a digit of number with a different digit   
public static IEnumerable<string> SingleDigitReplacements(string number)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < number.Length; ++i)
        foreach(char c in _Digits.Where(d => number[i] != d))
            yield return ReplaceAt(number,i,c);
}

// returns all strings formed from replacing k digits of number with different digits
public static IEnumerable<string> KDigitReplacements(string number, int k)
{
    var nums = new HashSet<string>();
    nums.Add(number);
    for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        var inner = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach(var num in nums)
            foreach(string replacement in SingleDigitReplacements(num))
                inner.Add(replacement);
        foreach(string replacement in inner)
            nums.Add(replacement);
    }
    foreach(string num in nums)
        yield return num;
}
```

The intention is, for example, if I call

```
KDigitReplacements("01", 1)
```

that would yield

```
"11", "21", ..., "91" (all replacements of 1st digit)
"00", "02", ..., "09" (all replacements of 2nd digit)
```

and

```
KDigitReplacements("01", 2)
```

would yield the above plus the combined results of applying the same procedure to each of the above strings. But, I don't want any repeats. How I'm doing this is pretty bulky and yet I can't think of a better way.

Comment: What is your question? Does the code you have work? If not, what does it do now and what do you want it to do instead? If you need help, please provide a good [mcve] and explain precisely what it is the code isn't doing that you want it to do.

Comment: If your code works and you are looking for tips on how to improve it, [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is a better place for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's a problem of combinatorics, therefore you have to take all options.

First you can shorten the code. The Hashset implements the interface IEnumerable (see [https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)) hence instead of

```
foreach(string num in nums)
    yield return num;
```

write

```
return nums
```

the same on the

```
foreach(string replacement in SingleDigitReplacements(num))
            inner.Add(replacement);
    foreach(string replacement in inner)
        nums.Add(replacement);
```

instead write

```
foreach(string replacement in SingleDigitReplacements(num))
            nums.Add(replacement);
```

Second: If you need Performance, look for [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx)

Greetings Noran